# Maven unable to find org.eclipse.swt

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm attempting to port a project over from the Eclipse build system to the Maven / Leiningen build system. Unfortunately, I am unable to compile due to `org.eclipse.swt` not being found (despite it being up on [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.eclipse|swt|3.3.0-v3346|jar).

I notice SWT has a number of platform-specific jars. However, I'm confused - why should I need those to build (as opposed to executing).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Tycho` if you attempt to port an Eclipse RCP project. Tycho resolves dependencies regarding your Manifest files.